# Is it possible to ask junit to run a prescript before doing tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-boot

Is it possible to ask junit to run a prescript before doing tests ?

I don't wan't to run `@Before` as it will only initialize one test.
Neither `setUp` as I think it does the same thing.

There is ClassRule but it require to maintain a list of the Test.

A nice thing would be to have an entry test file so I could run my java code from here.

Example of usage :

- "the whole test require a database to be started."
- "a migration script need to be run"

I know people would tell me to run this in gradle before or another build tool.

I am using flyway for the database migration and the version number is stored in my spring boot yaml file. I choose to configure flyway using java instead of gradle because gradle needs to use the command line to do migration so it can't be run with jenkins.

Also, I don't know how I could read the value of my yaml in gradle, neither to run a script.

Comment: I marked this as a possible duplicate because "prescript" is ambiguous if you are just talking about Junit. Junit is simply a Java tool that runs unit tests. There are several ways to run Junit (including Gradle). The duplicate question addresses how to run set up steps in a portable _Junit_ way, but you may be asking the wrong question and may want to ask about how to do this in Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) annotation.

It indicates that the static method to which is attached must be executed *once* and *before all tests* in the class. That happens when the test methods share computationally expensive setup (e.g. connect to database, connection pool).

For example an expensive operation of Hibernate `SessionFactory` initialization:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use @Autowired ? How do I load the context in this static ?

Comment: @BigDong of course you are right, it's impossible to do, it is bad example. I've updated with another one. Thank you for this remark.